# MvcSiteMapProvider - Dynamic SiteMaps not appearing in navigation when Starting Depth > 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using the [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) library for creating sitemaps and navigation in an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application. I've created a dynamic sitemap provider, but none of the nodes seem to appear when I set starting depth level to > 1. When I set it to level 1, the dynamically created nodes appear just fine.

Here is my sitemap file:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Help" controller="Help" action="Index" key="Help">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Help Section" controller="Help" action="Section"
        dynamicNodeProvider="MyLibrary.HelpNodeProvider, MyLibrary" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>

<mvcSiteMapNode title="About" clickable="false">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Accessibility" controller="Info" action="Accessibility" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Terms &amp; Conditions" controller="Info" action="Terms" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Privacy" controller="Info" action="Privacy" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

...and my HelpNodeProvider class:

```
namespace MyLibrary.Sitemap
{
    public class HelpNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
    {
        public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
        {
            DynamicNode test = new DynamicNode();
            test.Title = "Help Item 1";
            test.Controller = "Help";
            test.Action = "Section";
            test.RouteValues.Add("sectionName", "item1");
            test.ParentKey = "Help";

            return new List<DynamicNode>()
            {
                test
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the root of the 'Help' page, if I add the following MvcSiteMap helper code:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(2, 2)
```

...it doesn't output anything, but if I change the starting level to '1':

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(1, 2)
```

...it outputs the following:

- About

  - Accessibility
  - Terms & Conditions
  - Privacy
- Help

  - Help Item 1

...as you can see, the 'Help item 1' dynamic node is present. But I the set the starting node to '2' on the root 'About' page I get the following:

- Accessibility
- Terms & Conditions
- Privacy

So the 'About' page with static sub-navigation appears to output properly, but the 'Help' page with dynamic sub-navigation doesn't. Want am I doing wrong?

Comment: Been having the same problem. The Menu method has an overload to specify the starting node. I just don't know how to specify/instance the node